# How do you test for an empty input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm trying to test to see if an input field matches one of my factories where the field is empty.

```
address => {:first_name => '', :last_name => ''}
```

When checking for what is in the input field I've been using this:

```
assert_select '#first_name[value=?]', address.first_name
```

Except this does not work if the first name is blank. I'll get this error and the test fails.

```
Expected at least 1 element matching "#first_name[value='']", found 0.
<false> is not true.
```

This makes sense because the code generated will not have the value attribute. Is there a better way to verify the value of an input field?

As of now to test for this I can check if the address field is blank then check if there is an input field without a value attribute. But this is messy and verbose.

Example of a universal check that works but is lengthy:

```
if address.first_name.blank?
  assert_select '#first_name[value]', 0
  assert_select '#first_name[type=text]', 1
else
  assert_select '#first_name[value=?]', address.first_name
end
```

Related Information I'm using:
Hpricot 0.8.1
Nokogiri 1.1.1
Rails 2.2.2
Thoughtbot-Shoulda 2.0.5
Webrat 0.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assert that an input element is empty in Ruby on Rails tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308158/how-to-assert-that-an-input-element-is-empty-in-ruby-on-rails-tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
assert_select "#first_name" do
  assert_select "[value=?]", address.first_name unless address.first_name.blank?
end
```

I don't think I can get it any shorter. If it is a recurring pattern in your test case, you could extract it to a custom assertion:

```
def assert_has_value_unless_blank(selector, value)
  assert_select selector do
    assert_select "[value=?]", value unless value.blank?
  end
end

assert_has_value_unless_blank "#first_name", address.first_name
```

Comment: This does not seem to test that the input element is empty, it just skips the test for the value attribute if the passed in value is blank.