# How to assert that an input element is empty in Ruby on Rails tests

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, testing

I want to ensure that the password fields are empty when editing a user. How do I do this in a functional test?

I've tried both of these variants:

```
assert_select "input[name=?][value=?]", 'user[password1]', ''
```

and

```
assert_tag :tag => "input", :attributes => {:name => "user[password1]", :value => ""}
```

Both fail because there is no `value=` attribute present in the generated html. I don't see any way of testing that an attribute is *not* present in the generated html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
assert_select 'input:not([value])[name="user[password1]"]', true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm! The last param `true` does not seem to be needed, though.

Answer (score 1):

in cucumber/webrat sth like `page.should_not have_xpath("//input[contains(@value, \"\")]")` works

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at these alternative testing frameworks, but have not made the plunge yet. Stuff like this makes the effort seem worthwile though.